# How to return from multiple layers in the call stack?

Tags: exception, rust, exit

Assume we have a game loop, along the lines of this Python pseudocode

```py
def handle_events():
    for e in get_frame_events():
        if e.type == CloseEvent:
            raise SuccessfulExit()

def gameloop():
    while True:
        handle_events()
        handle_physics()
        render()

def main():
    try: gameloop()
    except SuccessfulExit: return
```

We are able to exit the program from `handle_events` while unwinding the stack and calling all destructors. If the call stack up to `handle_events` were deeper, it would be unpractical to return a boolean indicating whether the program should exit all the way up to `main`.

I am aware of `process::exit`, but it is rather harsh and does not call destructors but exits immediately. Is it possible to do something like in the code above in Rust?

Comment: may be helpful https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/cleanly-exiting-the-program-in-rust/5501/3

Comment: this is a poor design in the first place

Comment: @Stargateur Please tell me how this can be done better

Answer (score 2):

Return an error and match on the error in the main function:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Error {
    SuccessfulExit,
}

fn handle_events() -> Result<(), Error> {
    // for e in get_frame_events() {
        // if e.kind == CloseEvent {
            return Err(Error::SuccessfulExit);
        // }
    // }

    // Ok(())
}

fn gameloop() -> Result<(), Error> {
    loop {
        handle_events()?;
        // handle_physics();
        // render();
    }
}

fn main() {
    match gameloop() {
        Ok(()) | Err(Error::SuccessfulExit) => return,
        Err(e) => eprintln!("Error: {:?}", e),
    }
}
```

---

Technically, you could also cause a panic and then catch it, but that's a terrible idea.

Comment: I understand this, but in my actual application `handle_events` will within 5 nested calls and returning a Result everywhere just for this one case seems tedious.